# How do I remove the App name from my flipping live tile on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, live-tile

I'm using this template TileWide310x150PeekImage03 from the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761491.aspx). On the example image, the name of the App is not displayed on the image, but on my App the name of the app remains.

This ruins the UI of my tile because the App name is displayed within the image of my flipping live tile. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 4):

Add `branding="none"` to the binding element in the template XML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to add branding="logo" to one side and branding="none" to the other?

Comment: Consider add it to your question and don't forget to accept the answer provided by @PulseLab after that.